# How to multiply string value to longint in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below data which I want to multiply together, column A times column B to get column C.

A has datatype string and B has datatype long.

```
A      B
16%    894
15%    200
```

I have tried this expression in query `cast(A as int)*B` but it is giving me an error.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a `long` datatype, do you mean `bigint`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the cast in SQL Server is `CAST(expression AS TYPE);`

As you cannot convert '%' to an integer so you have to replace that with an empty character
as below:

```
SELECT cast(replace(A,'%','') AS int);
```

Finally you can write as below:

```
SELECT (cast(replace(A,'%','') AS int)/100.00)*B as C;
```

Comment: How does your answer improve on mine?

Comment: I did not notice your answer. I answered based on my previous same type of operation I did. There are mysql and mysql server forum where many use cases are mentioned regarding Casting and all other operations. By the way why are you asking me this question?

Comment: Asking because its not normal to add the same answer a second time.

Comment: Please, don't overthink. And it is a very common answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the '%' symbol before attempting your cast. And assuming you are actually wanting to calculate the percentage, then you also need to divide by 100.00.

```
cast(replace(A,'%','') as int)/100.00*B
```

Note: You need to use `100.00` rather than `100` to force decimal arithmetic instead of integer. Or you could cast as decimal(9,2) instead of int - either way ensures you get an accurate result.

You may well want to reduce the number of decimal points returned, in which case cast it back to your desired datatype e.g.

```
cast(cast(replace(A,'%','') as int)/100.00*@ as decimal(9,2))
```

Note: `decimal(9,2)` is just an example - you would use whatever precision and scale you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below way -

```
select cast(left(A, patindex('%[^0-9]%', A+'.') - 1) as int)*B
from tablename
```